# gspread/OAuth2: authenticated default gmail account (used early in ClientLogin)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have been using gspread (authenticated via ClientLogin) for a last year. Now I would like to use OAuth2. I've followed tutorial from gspread site: http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html

The problem is that this method creates new "Email address" (in console.developers.google) which doesn't have an access to spreadsheets - all spreadsheets should be shared again. This is really difficult if you have 1000+ spreadsheets.

The question is: how to authenticated with OAuth2 my default gmail account (that I've been using to access via ClientLogin)?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/

But I modified code from point 1.2: http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/#comment-2026863410

Result - some spreadsheets are available, some not and I have no idea why (same entries in access list)...

Comment: the new email address you mentioned, is it the one in "client_email"?

Comment: I've been using example@gmail.com (with its password) for a last year to auth with ClientLogin. All spreadsheets belong to example@gmail.com. I would like to be able to access all spreadsheets via OAuth2 without changing any permission separately for every spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you get an error when trying to access those spreadsheets you say are not available?

Comment: maybe old vs new style spreadsheets. Or google for business accounts?

Comment: Ok. it seems that there are two issues: 1.Bug in gspread (which I've just reported). 2. Google API related issue - Google Sheets API returns only 500 results (thus, if you have more spreadsheets that are not among results -> gspread raises SpreadsheetNotFound). So, auth via OAuth2 described in EDIT works.

Comment: @TomCod this Python based spreadsheet API/tool might be of interest: https://gridspree.io  Code: https://github.com/asm-products/gridspree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that code from EDIT works. Thus, this is working solution:

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/

But I modified code from point 1.2: http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/#comment-2026863410

The only problem is that Google Sheets API returns only 500 results (thus, if using gspread when you have more spreadsheets that are not among results -> gspread raises SpreadsheetNotFound).