# Sharing Google Sheet with API Credentials - Domain Not Found

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gspread

I'm a beginner trying to access a google sheet via python `gspread`. I'm following these instructions: `https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2`.

I believe I've successfully created my credentials: `survivor-points-update@update-survivor-gspread.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. When I try to share the google sheets document with this email, I get an email response telling me delivery failed because the domain couldn't be found. More specifically:

```
DNS Error: 19491 DNS type 'mx' lookup of update-survivor-gspread.iam.gserviceaccount.com responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: update-survivor-gspread.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I've found this [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790016/how-to-connect-to-google-sheets-without-sharing-the-sheet-with-a-service-account) but I got a `401 error: The OAuth client was not found.`:

```
client_id=<CLIENTID_FROM_GOOGLE_DEVLOPER_CONSOLE>
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/
scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
access_type=offline
response_type=code
```

I've tried setting up my credentials a second time, but those don't work either. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** On a hunch, I tried to share other documents with my two service accounts, and that didn't help.

**EDIT 2:** I tried a few different settings and scope as suggested in the [git hub issue](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/729).

My main code is:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(cred_path, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open(gsheet).sheet1
```

With this scope, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-b2d4b9300652>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet = client.open(gsheet).sheet1
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 79, in request
    raise APIError(response)

APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

If I change:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 37, in finditem
    return next((item for item in seq if func(item)))

StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-22-b2d4b9300652>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet = client.open(gsheet).sheet1
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 131, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound

SpreadsheetNotFound
```

I've tried enabling the google sheets API to both my projects and run the code again with both the scope options.

If I run `client.openall()` it returns only the following list: `[<Spreadsheet 'Access Rights Spreadsheet' id:1TwF6neGtogHAsqu4vjIiGWpfUPiQmVFgF5kR8k_8jC0>]`

Is there another scope I can add or API I can enable?

**EDIT 3:** I don't know how `[<Spreadsheet 'Access Rights Spreadsheet' id:1TwF6neGtogHAsqu4vjIiGWpfUPiQmVFgF5kR8k_8jC0>]` was shared with me. I thought it was just one that everybody had.

When I run this:

```
bk = client.open_by_key('1TwF6neGtogHAsqu4vjIiGWpfUPiQmVFgF5kR8k_8jC0')
sht = bk.get_worksheet(0)
l = sht.get_all_values()
```

`l` is an empty list. `bk.worksheets()` returns `[<Worksheet 'Sheet1' id:0>]` so I don't see any other data.

Comment: Did you try to access this spreadsheet from your Python code after you had shared it?

Comment: Here's a similar issue: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/729
Could you take a look and check if the solution works for you?

Comment: Thanks @Burnash, appreciate the help. I've put a comprehensive summary of what I tried after reading the github issue. Happy to try something else.

Comment: The correct scope is `scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']`. How was the spreadsheet from the `client.openall()` return value shared with your client account? (The one named 'Access Rights Spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you. More troubleshooting attempts above.